# data model limit rows per user

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints, limits, postgresql-13

This is regarding to postgres that I was asked to create data model which has a relationship with user.

For example a new data model called Comment M:1 User, but while creating the data model is it possible to set restriction that only 100 commend records can be created?
Might not even link them with a PK might be just a pure column with `user_id`.

Usually if this need to be done, I do it within the RESTful api request to do checks if there's already 100 comments created by the user, but I told to do it on the data model side.  I tried googling around but might not be using the correct keywords so a little bit lost here that I want to make sure this is possible with just within one table creation (comment)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / advices.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a Constraint or a Trigger, but this would honestly be a bad design pattern, in my opinion. I think this kind of logic is better managed in the application / API layer.

Comment: @J.D. but what happens if a **new** app starts writing to the db? It won't know anything about the old app's constraints. If you want to ensure a max. of 100 comments **full stop**, you're better off with  trigger!

Comment: @Vérace Yea I agree a Trigger is probably the better route of the two, but I still think this is something that should be enforced in the application layer instead, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html) is a good approach. Also, it's worth considering using [ARRAY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html) to manage your comment. For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_customers, tb_comments;

CREATE TABLE tb_customers (
  customer_id uuid primary key, 
  username text
);

CREATE TABLE tb_comments (
  customer_id uuid primary key, 
  comment text[]
);

ALTER TABLE tb_comments ADD CONSTRAINT tb_comments_constr01 
  CHECK ( array_length(comment, 1) <= 10); -- LIMIT 10 comment 

INSERT INTO tb_customers VALUES 
  ('53003bcb-3d1e-4955-96c0-272719e9762d', 'username_01'),
  ('07c01749-5ec2-4d38-9b74-15168fe185f5', 'username_02'),
  ('ab68a33d-ddb0-4bc5-af75-a7d17cb9c157', 'username_03');
 
INSERT INTO tb_comments (customer_id, comment) values ('07c01749-5ec2-4d38-9b74-15168fe185f5', array['$1'])
ON CONFLICT (customer_id) 
DO UPDATE SET comment = array_append(tb_comments.comment, '$1');

INSERT INTO tb_comments (customer_id, comment) values ('ab68a33d-ddb0-4bc5-af75-a7d17cb9c157', array['$2'])
ON CONFLICT (customer_id) 
DO UPDATE SET comment = array_append(tb_comments.comment, '$2');

INSERT INTO tb_comments (customer_id, comment) values ('53003bcb-3d1e-4955-96c0-272719e9762d', array['$3'])
ON CONFLICT (customer_id) 
DO UPDATE SET comment = array_append(tb_comments.comment, '$3');
```

Comment: Nice! They may want to add another `CHECK (array_ndims(comment) = 1)` to restrict the arrays to 1-dimensional only.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying out the trigger since I am new at this, documents seems straight forward and found some samples online but somehow I kept on getting errors :( anyways thank you so much for the suggestion and the sample of Array